# Let users sell video in my website

Tags: plugins, videos, e-commerce

I have a WordPress website with version 5.9 and I want functionality to sell video content.

These videos could be uploaded by the website users and they can decide the price of their uploaded videos. I also want to keep a small fee as commission.

What plugin do you recommend for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an education website [LearnDash](https://www.learndash.com/) could be a good choice. It's a good plugin but doesn't include a free version. Users can register as teacher and sell their courses.

Other option could be the combination of [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and a marketplace plugin like [Dokan](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dokan-lite/) or [YITH WooCommerce Multi Vendor](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-multi-vendor/).

Both has nearly same features.
I personally prefer Dokan because it offers a good minimum free version at WordPress repository.